# biblatex and \nocite{*} problem

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, xetex, biber, recursion

I don't need any cites in my text, but I need the bibliography in the end of the book. When I put `\nocite{*}` command, I have the deep recursion problem with `biber` after `xelatex`.

`biber` version 2.7, cache is clear

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%
\usepackage[%
defernumbers = true,
backend=biber,
bibstyle=gost-numeric,
citestyle=gost-footnote,
language=auto,
babel=other,
sorting=ntvy,
doi=false,
eprint=false,
isbn=false,
dashed=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{astrsaints.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}{astrsaints.bib}
@Book{marian,
    ids        = {marian},
    title      = {Святые и подвижники благочестия земли Астраханской},
    location   = {Астрахань},
    publisher  = {Тип. «Новая линия»},
    year       = {2010},
    totalpage = {532},
    editor = {игумен Иосиф (Марьян)},
    editortype = {compiler},
    langid     = {russian},
    language   = {russian},
    keywords   = {commons},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    %
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=secbib, title={Общие работы}, keyword = commons]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make sure that your MWE actually compiles. You are missing `\begin{filecontents}` and `{\jobname.bib}` has to go after `\begin{filecontents}` and not `\usepackage{filecontents}`

Comment: Avoid loading `xunicode` and `xltxtra` if you have an up-to-date TeX system; instead, do `\usepackage{fontspec}`.  Also `fontenc` is redundant.

Comment: @egreg, I edited my answer to include your recommendations.

Answer (score 4):

The problem there seems to be that you are defining a key alias in your bib entry which is exactly equal to the original key.

So, if you remove `ids = {marian},` which does you no good anyway, or change it to `ids = {marian2},` biber should handle it fine.

**Edit**: Here is the full code I've used (refined according to egreg's recommendations in the comments):

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openany]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
%
\usepackage[%
defernumbers = true,
backend=biber,
bibstyle=gost-numeric,
citestyle=gost-footnote,
language=auto,
babel=other,
sorting=ntvy,
doi=false,
eprint=false,
isbn=false,
dashed=false
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{astrsaints.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{astrsaints.bib}
@Book{marian,
    ids        = {marian2},
    title      = {Святые и подвижники благочестия земли Астраханской},
    location   = {Астрахань},
    publisher  = {Тип. «Новая линия»},
    year       = {2010},
    totalpage = {532},
    editor = {игумен Иосиф (Марьян)},
    editortype = {compiler},
    langid     = {russian},
    language   = {russian},
    keywords   = {commons},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Общие работы}, keyword = commons]
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but both tips doesn't works. If I will make `\cite` in text and remove `\nocite{*}` — no problems with bibliographies.

Comment: @МаксимБурдин, I'll post the complete code I've used, for I had to make some adjustments, given your MWE was not really compilable. Perhaps it is useful.

Comment: It's very good!

Comment: Is there any ways to do `\nocite{*}` biblatex bibliography without `filecontents` package? I don't want duplicate bib-entries in preamble at all.

Comment: @МаксимБурдин You don't need `filecontents` in your actual document (no matter if you use `\nocite` or not). It is just here to make the example self-contained.

Comment: @МаксимБурдин, yes, as moewe explained you should save your entries in a separate bib file, and call it with `\addbibresource`. The use of `filecontents` is just to make the MWE more convenient here in the site.